# Taxonomy term template is not working

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I have such a question, there is a taxonomy 'custom' for example, and it has a term 'speacial'. And I want this term to hook my custom template. For standard taxonomies, taxonomy-custom.php is displayed, and for this, taxonomy-custom-special.php should work, but for some reason it does not work.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the spelling is correct? You've used two different spellings here.

Comment: Yes, spelling is ok, there was a code in functions.php, that hard-coded a template for this taxonomy. Thanks for watching!